# Pygame "TypeError: must be 2-item sequence, not builtin_function_or_method"

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror

I want to run the code to open a Pygame screen that can be drawn by dragging the mouse. But IDLE always says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python32/Pygame/draw", line 36, in <module>
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,WHITE,spot,radius)
TypeError: must be 2-item sequence, not builtin_function_or_method
```

---

```
    import pygame
    pygame.init()

    screen=pygame.display.set_mode([800,600])
    pygame.display.set_caption("Draw lines")



    WHITE=(225,225,225)
    radius=10

    mousedown=False



    keep_going=True
    while keep_going:



       for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                keep_going=False

            if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mousedown=True
            if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                        mousedown=False



        if mousedown:
            spot=pygame.mouse.get_pos

                pygame.draw.circle(screen,WHITE,spot,radius)
             pygame.display.update()



    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Also, please try to format the code correctly. It looks like you've used tabs mixed with spaces. [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends to use only spaces. You can select your code here in the "edit" window and just press "Ctrl-K", but there are still other indentation problems.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `()` to call the function `get_pos()`, so Python gives the function as an object, not the result of the function, that's why you are getting this error.

```
if mousedown:
    spot=pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    pygame.draw.circle(screen,WHITE,spot,radius)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thanks!^_^  And why can we use "event.pos"  without ()?

Comment: For example：      
      if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            spot=event.pos
……                                                             can run.

Comment: @Inteyerry that's Python's magic !! Everything is an object, variables, classes and functions. This can be useful to store a function elsewhere, or rename it

Comment: @Inteyerry another way to see what you did, you just created a shortcut to call the function `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` with `spot()`. You could also fix your first code by using `pygame.draw.circle(screen,WHITE,spot(),radius)`

Comment: Oh,I think that I understand.Maybe "get_pos()" is a functions,and "event.pos" is a variable and store a function. I should learn more.Thank you^_^

Comment: Oh,sir.When I used pygame.draw.circle(screen,WHITE,spot(),radius) ,computer says:"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spot'"

Comment: Dear sir,why can computer say the words?Please tell me.

Comment: @Inteyerry `event.pos` gives you the value of the `pos` attribute of the `event` object which is a tuple consisting of two numbers. It's like a variable inside of another object that you can assign and retrieve with the dot notation, for example you can also assign a new value to event.pos: `event.pos = (90, 100)`. Better read a tutorial about [classes and object oriented programming](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_classes&lang=en#section_12) to learn more about it.

Comment: @Inteyerry just call `spot = pygame.mouse.get_pos()` and then use spot here `pygame.draw.circle(screen,WHITE,spot,radius)`. `spot` is a tuple object which you can't call like a function, so `spot()` will raise an error. I can't say why you get the `"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spot'"` and you'd have to post more code, so that we can see what you're doing.

Comment: I see.The code is all,At last,can you recommend me some books on classes and object oriented programming?Thank goodness.So many books,I do not which book to read.

Comment: Check out the link to Program Arcade Games above and also read the next chapter about sprites, because it's a good practise for OOP. That should be enough for the beginning.